# Cannot read property 'value' of null from HTML input

Tags: javascript, object

I have fixed it already. I cannot figure it our why am I getting "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of null"? The error shows up on the "var name = document.getElementById("name").value;" line.

```
 var colors = [];

 function Save() {
 var name = document.getElementById("name").value;
 var rgb = document.getElementById("colordisplay").innerHTML;
 var opacity = document.getElementById("div").style.opacity;
 colors.push({
    name_prop:name,
    rgb_prop:rgb,
    opacity_prop:opacity,
 });
 //pass the array into the dropdown list
 var select = document.getElementById("selectColor");
 for (var i = 0; i < colors.length; i++) {
    var opt = colors[i];
    var el = document.createElement("option");
    el.innerHTML = opt;
    el.value = opt;
    select.appendChild(el);
    console.log(colors);
  }
 }
```

Comment: It depends when `Save()` gets called.

Comment: There are errors reported in the browser console! You should *always* have that open when you're testing out something like this.

Comment: `colors[i].length` ??

Answer (score 0):

Insert function is not called anywhere in your JSBin